# foreach loop in PHP with as statement in it

Tags: php

Can someone explain me foreach loop in PHP
specifically in this example

```
<?php
    $age = array("Peter"=>"35","Michel"=>"37","Finch"=>"43");
    foreach($age as $x => x_values) // here I am getting confussion
    {
        echo "Key = ".$x."value = ".$x_values;
        echo"<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ole Haugset for the help

Comment: Hi sir Can I get your email Id I have a problem in my code which I want to discuss with you please

Answer (score 1):

You have not valid variable `x_values`, should be `$x_values`:

```
<?php
$age = array("Peter"=>"35","Michel"=>"37","Finch"=>"43");
foreach($age as $x => $x_values) // here I am getting confussion
{
    echo "Key = ".$x."value = ".$x_values;
    echo"<br>";
}
?>
```

`foreach` iterate through array, in your case it's `$age`. Variable `$x` get the keys from your array: `Peter`, `Michel`, `Finch`. Variable `$x_values` get the values: `35`, `37`, `43`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $age = array("Peter"=>"35","Michel"=>"37","Finch"=>"43");
    foreach($age as $x => $x_values) // here I am getting confussion
       {
           echo "Key = ".$x."value = ".$x_values;
           echo"<br>";
       }
?>
```

$age= your array

$x = your array key

$x_values = your array value

```
echo "Key = ".$x."value = ".$x_values;

//ex: key = Peter Value = 35 (display like that)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nims patel for the help now i got it completely

Answer (score 0):

Foreach takes the form of  `key` => `value` so your array.  Now the real problem you are having is syntax errors.

Like this `foreach($age as $x => x_values)` missing the `$` for the `x_values`.

This is ok `"Key = ".$x."value = ".$x_values;` but we can simply do this `"Key = $x value = $x_values";` instead.  PHP will interpolate (interpret and replace) variables within double quotes.  You can also do them this way `"Key = {$x} value = {$x_values}";`  Which saves a few characters over concatenation `.` and allows you to place a variable next to a word like this `"$avalue"` is seen as `$avalue` but `"{$a}value"` is seen as `$a."value"`.  Hope that makes sense.

That said, this `'$a'` is just the string `$a` because it's in single quotes.

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35","Michel"=>"37","Finch"=>"43");
foreach($age as $x => $x_values) // here I am getting confussion
   {
       echo "Key = $x value = $x_values"; //fixed this
       echo"<br>";
   }
```

Output

```
Key = Peter value = 35
Key = Michel value = 37
Key = Finch value = 43
```

Comment: Thanks ArtisticPhoenix for the help now i got it completely

Comment: Hi ArtisticPhoenix ,Sir can I please get your email id Because I have a problem in my code so that I can discuss with you please  my whatsapp number is 8186948065